# Vue-router beforeEach stuck in infinite loop when using next()

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm having this problem where i cant use `next('/login')`. This is my code:

```
*/ all imports that are needed 

Vue.use(Router);

const routes = [
{path: '/', component: Home},
{path: '/admin', component: Admin},
{path: '/login', component: Login}]

var route = new Router({
routes: routes,
mode: 'history' });

route.beforeEach((to, from , next) => {
console.log(to.fullPath)
next('/login');
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: route,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App
  }
})
```

It works when i only use next() but when i give the next() function a route it's stuck within an infinite loop

[console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAyKN.png)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to prevent to call `next('/login')` if you are already directing to `'/login'`.

For example:

```
route.beforeEach((to, from , next) => {
  console.log(to.fullPath)
  if (to.path !== '/login') {
    next('/login');
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it

Comment: This still breaks in some cases. When testing this, if a user clicks to navigate to another protected route, the infinite loop starts again. Using `afterEach` like `app.router.afterEach((to, from) => {` with `app.router.push('/login)` does not have that issue.

Comment: @learnsomemore - could you elaborate?  Do you mean I should be testing `to.path != '/login'` inside after each and redirect using `app.router.push('login')` instead of `next`?